# Remove the duplicate password warning

Tags: safari, password

I'm going through all my Safari passwords and updating the ones that Apple is warning me are no good for one reason or another.  About half of the warnings are not accurate because Apple is warning me that I am using the password multiple times for different websites, but those websites all use the same account.  The passwords must be the same.

I'd like some help accomplishing any one of the following:

1. Merge or group the two (or more) websites in Safari so that they show up as rightfully sharing the password.
2. Disabling the warning about duplicate password use.  Either for specific sites or entirely.